# Name of a particular matrix with $M_{ij}=t_{\min(i,j)}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, terminology

I'm looking to see if there's a name for a particular type of matrix $M_{ij}=t_{\min(i,j)}$, ie.:

\begin{bmatrix}
t_1 & t_1 & t_1 & t_1 \\
t_1 & t_2 & t_2 & t_2 & \cdots\\
t_1 & t_2 & t_3 & t_3 \\
t_1 & t_2 & t_3 & t_4 \\ 
 & \vdots & & & \ddots 
\end{bmatrix}

Such a matrix has determinant $t(t_2-t_1)(t_3-t_2)(t_4-t_3)\cdots$ and its inverse is a very simple tridiagonal matrix. But it isn't a [Vandermonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix) or a [Moore matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore_matrix). It looks like it's an [alternant matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternant_matrix), but that doesn't capture any of the interesting properties of the determinant or inverse. It seems like something with these special properties should be named or well-known somewhere.

This matrix came up in looking at a particular probabilistic process, where $P(x_1,t_1 ; x_2,t_2;\cdots)\propto \exp(-\frac{1}{2}\vec{x}^T M^{-1}\vec{x})$ (hence the significance of the simple tridiagonal structure of $M^{-1}$).

Comment: This is an example of a GCD matrix in the wider sense of this word, i.e., of an $n\times n$-matrix whose $\left(i,j\right)$-th element is $a_{u_i \wedge u_j}$, where $u_1, u_2, \ldots, u_n$ are some $n$ elements of a lattice $L$, and $a_k$ is a number for each $k \in L$. There is noticeable literature about these matrices, specifically when $L$ is the divisor lattice of the integers (see, e.g., https://mathoverflow.net/questions/262153/the-gcd-matrix-generalizing-a-result-of-smith ), and I'm pretty sure at least some of it considers the general case, but I can't find it right now.

Comment: Ah, these slides by Bruce Sagan seem friendly: http://users.math.msu.edu/users/sagan/Slides/mfp5.pdf

Comment: Aha -- a [meet matrix](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.laa.2008.05.025).